# Creating static drop down list in Jaspersoft ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, prompt, ireport

I'm creating a report in "Jaspersoft iReport designer 5.6.0". What I'm trying to do is add a parameter (a static list that contains values such as: 6 months, 3 months ...). When the user chooses one of these options, I should be able in the Report query, to get the value that the user has chosen, so I can deliver the results upon that selection. I don't want to use jasper server.

Is this possible?

this is my query:

```
SELECT
     DISTRICT."DKEY" AS DISTRICT_DKEY,
     DISTRICT."PROVINCE_ID" AS DISTRICT_PROVINCE_ID,
     DISTRICT."DISTRICT" AS DISTRICT_DISTRICT
     DISTRICT."DURATION" AS DISTRICT_DURATION
FROM
     "dbo"."DISTRICT" DISTRICT
where DISTRICT."DKEY" = $P{parameter1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iReport you can **not** create a static list (combobox) of your different month's you can only prompt for the insertion of parameter.

[image: Parameter request]

User will need to **input manually** 3,6 ecc.

```
<parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="true">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[3]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

iReport is not developed to be used by your client, but to be used by you when developing the report.

If you do not wish to use the [jasperserver](/questions/tagged/jasperserver), you can develop your own application for user to select data ecc. Below you find an example of a [java](/questions/tagged/java) [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) application, asking to select month and generating preview of the report (you need to fix the connection settings and provide correct path for the jrxml file):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer;

public class JasperReportInterface extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5430239481089683268L;
  private JComboBox<MonthItem> selectMonts;

  public JasperReportInterface() {
    super("Jasper Report Interface");
    jbInit();
  }

  private void jbInit() {
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    selectMonts = new JComboBox<MonthItem>();
    selectMonts.addItem(new MonthItem(3));
    selectMonts.addItem(new MonthItem(6));

    this.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Select month:"), new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 2,
            2), 0, 0));
    this.getContentPane().add(selectMonts, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2,
            2), 0, 0));

    JButton btnReport = new JButton("Generate report");
    btnReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnReport_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });

    this.getContentPane().add(btnReport,new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 2, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(2, 2, 2,
            2), 0, 0));
  }

  protected void btnReport_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String jasperFilePath = "jasper/myJasperFile.jrxml";

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Object v = selectMonts.getSelectedItem();
    if (v instanceof MonthItem) {
        parameters.put("parameter1", ((MonthItem) v).getMonth());
    }

    Connection conn = null; // Pass the connection to database or datasource

    JasperPrint report;
    try {
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jasperFilePath);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);
    } catch (JRException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error creating report: " + e1.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    JRViewer jrv = new JRViewer(report);
    JDialog viewer = new JDialog(this);
    viewer.setTitle("Print preview");
    viewer.getContentPane().add(jrv);
    viewer.pack();
    viewer.setSize(new Dimension(840, 600));
    viewer.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    viewer.setVisible(true);
  }

  class MonthItem {
    private int month;
    protected MonthItem(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return month + " months";
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JasperReportInterface ri = new JasperReportInterface();
    ri.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ri.setSize(400,100);
    ri.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ri.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Naturally you can also develop a similar web application.

Comment: dear i ended up building a form using extjs 4.2 and display the selected records in a grid  based on the user's parameter's. But how can i connect the grid to a jasper ireport?

Comment: @mikeb Your not really connecting it to ireport (ireport is just a tool to develop the report, the jrxml)... I need to see your grid to understand exactly what you need but normally the process is creating a JRDatasource (based on your parameters), calling the jrxml (report) and exporting to the format you like (pdf, excel, html ecc). In the report if the columns are dynamic you should consider using crosstable. If you pass another question with example of your datasource, desired layout jrxml ecc, , I can try to help you out.